# Stop my Batch from flicking accross the screen

Tags: batch-file, cmd

can anybody enlighten me to a way stopping my bat from flashing across the screen when executed? is there a way to stop the CMD window from doing this????

Comment: "flashing across the screen"? In what circumstances does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but to prevent the window opening and closing right away without seeing what it prints, use `pause` or `pause > nul` at the end of your batch file.

To get more/better help, please improve your question, f.e. describe "flashing across the screen" a bit.

EDIT: Your comment describes the problem better, you want to run the batch file without seeing the cmd window. If you start the batch file using a shortcut, you can run it in minimized mode by changing the shortcuts properties (from [this page](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/)):

1. Right click on the shortcut and
   choose Properties
2. In the Run: drop down, choose Minimized
3. Click OK
4. Double-click the shortcut to run the batch file in a minimized window state.

Comment: no no, Im mean i want the exact opposite i have a small batchfile thath runs and everytime when its executed it quickly flashes the CMD window its very uneasy on the eye if this happens every few seconds or so can i run a command with the exclusion of the window (is better said)

Comment: OK, this is a better explanation. Edited the answer.

Comment: i opted for the other method using .VBS thats listed only i try and run my VBA code which trigers it and i run into trouble because apparently it dosnt exist acording to VBA, I cant shell *.vbs like as with *.bat can I?